# java internal implementation of java.awt.Button?

Tags: java, events, button, listener

In the `java`'s implementation of `java.awt.Button` why does the `ActionListener` object is marked as transient?

from impl:    `transient ActionListener actionListener;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `transient` keyword in `Java` is used to indicate that a field should not be serialized.

*Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object.*

Here, `ActionListener` instance is a *suitable* candidate for marking as *transient*. we don't have any purpose to persist it. we use `transient` keyword when the class implements Serializable and we don't want the member to be persisted. we mark it as `transient` field.

Adding to that, `java.awt.Button` is a subclass of `java.awt.Component`, which implements `Serializable` interface. so, to restrict the *serialization* of `actionListener` member of the Button instance. *actionListener* field is marked as *transient*. Hope you understand

Comment: that's my doubt since we dont have any need to the object be persist can we make as transient?

Comment: we don't need to persist the state of ActionListener instance, since they are not part of the peristent state of Button

Comment: @VishalSantharam For members it is transient, For whole object you need not to do anything. Just don't implement serializable :)

Comment: Yes, Suresh is absolutely right. we use transient keyword when the class implements Serializable and we don't want the member to be persisted. we mark it as transient

Answer (score 1):

The keyword `transient` was added, to suppress the normal serialisation: instead the serialisation for that field is done in `readObject` and `writeObject`.

And the reason for that is the usage of `AWTEventMulticaster` to build the structure of event listeners. The methods readObject and writeObject delegate the serialisation for actionListener to that class too.